# How to present R lm object interaction coefficients in a table?

Tags: r, lm, interaction

Consider an lm fit object with interaction terms, e.g.:

```
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ interaction(gear, am, drop = T) - 1 + cyl, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
interaction(gear, am, drop = T)3.0  interaction(gear, am, drop = T)4.0  
                            35.478                              34.022  
interaction(gear, am, drop = T)4.1  interaction(gear, am, drop = T)5.1  
                            37.949                              36.946  
                               cyl  
                            -2.594
```

Is there a straightforward way to arrange the coefficients of (only) the interaction-terms in a two-dimensional table? e.g.:

```
gear    am = 0   am = 1   
3       35.478   NA   
4       34.022   37.949
5       NA       36.946
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `broom` package to get the information easily.  It's just a matter of adjusting the table you get to suit your needs:

```
model <- lm(formula = mpg ~ interaction(gear, am, drop = T) - 1 + cyl, data = mtcars)

library(broom)
tidy(model)[grep("interaction", tidy(model)$term),]
#                                term estimate std.error statistic      p.value
#1 interaction(gear, am, drop = T)3.0 35.47755  3.533483  10.04039 1.302118e-10
#2 interaction(gear, am, drop = T)4.0 34.02157  2.781402  12.23181 1.599806e-12
#3 interaction(gear, am, drop = T)4.1 37.94942  2.348132  16.16154 2.087857e-15
#4 interaction(gear, am, drop = T)5.1 36.94589  3.096187  11.93271 2.822201e-12
```

To get the table you want, you could do this:

```
dtab <- table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$am)
dtab[which(dtab != 0)] <- tidy(model)[grep("interaction", tidy(model)$term),]$estimate
dtab[which(dtab == 0)] <- NA
  #       0        1
  #3 35.47755         
  #4 34.02157 37.94942
  #5          36.94589
```

Comment: It also extends nicely to higher dimensions: if instead of `gear, am` we're interested in `gear, am, carb`, use `table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$am, mtcars$carb)`